# How to add key-pair values to an open csv file?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have used just letters to simplify my code below.My code writes a CSV file with columns of a,b,c,d values,each has 10 rows (length). I would like to add the average value of c and d to the same CSV file as well as an additional two columns each have one row for ave values. I have tried to append field names and write the new values but it didn't work.

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['a','b','c','d']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    total_c=0
    total_d=0
    for i in range(1,length):
        do something get a,b,c,d values.
        total_c += c
        total_d += d
        csv_writer.writerow({'a': a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d })
    mean_c=total_c /length
    mean_c=total_c /length
```

I expect to see something in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Could you show an example csv along with the expected result csv?

Comment: "Didn't work" is a much too imprecise error description. What is the error or output, what is the expected output and behavior (edit the question to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: does your csv file consist of the header? i would recommand to use python pandas to read csv file and manipulate the new columns.

Comment: Thank you Mr. J. Yes, i have headers they are fieldnames in my code.  I tried your solution it is working but it gives a different output than i need to see,it is my bad i should have added an expected pic at the beginning. Now,I have added a picture of expected result.

Comment: let me have look into it

Comment: i have changed according to your need, please verify. and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use pandas library to deal with csv file. I provided sample code below, I assume that csv file has no header present on the first line.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('out.csv',header=[['a','b','c','d'])
#making sure i am using copy of dataframe
avg_data = data.copy()

#creating new columns average in same dataframe
avg_data['mean_c'] = avg_data.iloc[:,2].mean(axis=1) 
avg_data['mean_d'] = avg_data.iloc[:,3].mean(axis=1) 

# writing updated data to csv file 
avg_data.to_csv('out.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: My project had a deadline and I had to find another solution-instead of adding columns, I just appended ave values end of the csv file. But thank you Mr. J for your time. This solution could have worked (if the syntax error at header (an extra square parentheses) removed)